# How to convert a numpy integer array to an integer

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I want to convert an integer array to an integer.
For example, if the array contains [2, 3, 1, 6] I want to get 2316.

Comment: Wasn't this "binary" just a second ago?

Comment: Loop on your array, concatenate each value into a string variable, use `int()` to make it a number.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes, it was. I reframed the question to make it look neat and to the point. :)

Comment: @Nic3500 But aren't strings immutable? Then how can I append something to them?

Comment: Like `print(int("".join(map(str, arr))))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1 (faster)

`integer = int("".join([str(x) for x in arr]))`

### Solution 2 (slower)

`integer = np.sum(np.array([(10**exp) * elem for (elem, exp) in zip(arr, reversed(range(len(arr))))]))`

### Background (Digging Deeper)

I just measured, the solution with string casting and joining and int casting is about 5 times faster on random numbers with 30 digits.

The rest of this background info is just for fun. :-)

#### Why is `int()` so much faster...

Using `int()` is very fast because the function in **cpython** [sourcecode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/main.c) corresponds to `Modules/main.c`'s `pymain_str_to_int()` which uses the C-Function `strtol` under the hood.

#### But I still want to be faster...

So basically you could become faster if you would build a module in C for python similar to this:

```
int fast_arraytoint( const char * arr, int * result )
{
    long val = 0;
    while( *arr ) {
        val = val*10 + (*arr++);
    }
    if (val > INT_MAX) {
        return -1;
    }

    *result = (int)val;
    return 0;
}
```

To dig even deeper one must figure out how python handles big integers, the ones that have a value higher than `INT_MAX` and integrate the C-Module so it could be handled for all types of python's ints.